# CompiledFunction with multiple outputs of different ranks

Tags: compile

Below is a simple compiled function `f` that gives multiple outputs.

```
f = Compile[{{a, _Real}}, Module[{k1=Table[i, {i, a}], k2=Table[i j, {i, a}, {j, a}]}, {k1, k2}]];
```

`CompilePrint[f]` shows `MainEvaluate` possibly because the ranks of `k1` and `k2` are diferent.

Sample evaluation `f[2]` gives the following warning and proceeds to uncompiled evaluation (probably because of the `MainEvaluate`)

```
CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 23; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>
```

Is there an alternate way to get multiple outputs of varying ranks from a compiled function without `MainEvaluate`?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1782/how-to-force-compile-to-return-multiple-results

Comment: That should answer your question.

Comment: @blochwave Thank you. Now that we have version 10, is it still not possible?