# How to handle ragged-list type argument in LibraryLink?

Tags: librarylink

Given that I have a ragged list as below,

```
raggedList = {U1, U2, ..., Un}
```

where, `ui` is a sublist($i=1,2,\cdots,n$) and their length are distinct. For example,

```
raggedList = 
  {{0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.75, 0.75, 0.8}, 
   {0.21, 0.25, 0.3, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8}, 
   {0.25, 0.3, 0.7, 0.8};
```

Namely, `raggedList` is not a ***tensor***. For this case, obviously, I cannot use `MArgument_getMTensor(Args[0])` to get that input.

Comment: You can use MathLink to pass such arguments.  This is easy but slower than MTensors.  Alternatively, you can flatten the array, then pass both its elements and the length of each sublist separately.  This will be faster.  I have used both approaches with LibraryLink.

Comment: Will [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1782/how-to-force-compile-to-return-multiple-results/121195#121195) representation help?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. I mean you can't directly. This is not yet supported in *LibraryLink*, there is a method to parse it via *MathLink*(now called WSTP), but that's another story. You can however always flatten your ragged array, store the lengths of each sub-array and pass that as another argument too for later formatting.

Another method would be to pad your array with symbols that you know should not appear as elements of your sub-list, things like -1 if you know the matrix is non-negative.

A lot of things are not supported in *LibraryLink* others include lists of strings and images.

Comment: Padding with symbols doesn't help because symbols can't be a part of a packed array and only packed arrays are supported directly by LibraryLink.  Images are supported directly.

Comment: If you pad with symbols you get NaN in your array. And I meant list of images is not supported. You will need to pass a 3D image and then slice it up.

Comment: That is not true, or at least not true on all platforms.  On my machine I get a LibraryFunction::cfta message.  Using things like `Infinity` *appears* to work *sometimes*, but in reality is not reliable and will result in random weird behaviour.

Comment: This is what happens when you try to use them: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19026/passing-back-nan-and-inf-to-c-via-mathlink

Comment: Hmm. That's possible. I tried with a toy example on my machine and it worked. Anyway. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: What version (and what OS) did you try with?  What array did you use exactly?  I am curious.  I tried on OS X with something like `{1,2,3,Null}`.

Comment: I use 10.4 I tried ```{1,1,1,Infinity}``` and on Window 8.1

Comment: Did you actually *type in* `Infinity`?  Or did you re-use some array returned by LibraryLink?  Infinities returned from LibraryLink do work sometimes and cause unexpected results at other times (thus they aren't really safe).  Infinities typed directly are symbols and the LibraryFunction call fails with them on OS X.

Comment: It was returned by a previous function. After doing some rigorous tests I managed to crash my functions several times so I will just remove this part from my answer.

Comment: Actually I also commit this "sin" in my IGraph/M package where some functions (`IGMotifs`) receive `Indeterminate` from LibraryLink as a packed array ... I'm not very comfortable about it and it's still in this state due to lack of time.  What I do there is that I use ``Developer`FromPackedArray`` to unpack the array with NaNs inside that I get from LibraryLink.  That seems to create normal `Indeterminate` symbols, which are no longer dangerous (so the package's user never gets any "dangerous" arrays).  I tested this on many platforms (Win/OS X/Linux 64 bit 10.4 and 10.3 RPi), but ...

Comment: ... I won't be at all surprised if it breaks someday.  I just need to get enough time to rewrite it ...