# Return multiple results from compiled function

Tags: compile

I wrote a function with `Compile` that produces a large array of data and later does some computation on it. Now, I want to return from the compiled function not only the final processed data, but also the raw data from which it originates. I know that `Compile` cannot deal with ragged arrays, that is I can not simply state `{x,y}` as the final line of the compiled function. What are the best strategies to resolve this problem if I don't won't to break up the one compiled function into two functions?

Comment: I edited this for clarity (as I found it a bit confusing). Please check that I did not break your intended meaning.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Sorry, yes I was trying to `Export` it first on-the-fly, but the function is not supported within `Compiled`. Now I would be glad to find a way of returning it as the output of `Compile` and then process it further from there within the MMA kernel.

Comment: Can you give a representative example? Something trivial that returns that same shape of data that you actually have. Maybe there's a simple way to encode all pieces into a single tensor.  You *can* actually return them as `{x,y}`, and I believe that the system will break from the compiled evaluation only at the very last operation. It does issue an annoying message though.

Comment: Maybe I can find a representative example later this evening. The data structure of it is `Dimensions[x]={n,2}` and `Dimensions[y]={m, 2, 2}`, where especially `m` is a large number up to 10^7-10^9. Yes, I tried it this way and one can ignore the error message, of course, but it makes it unbearably slow for such big arrays, unfortunately.

Comment: `Flatten` both arrays and `Join` them in the end. Back in _Mathematica_, separate the assays again and use `ArrayReshape` to restore the original shapes. This is not entirely for free, of course. But `Flatten` and `ArrayReshape`  applied to packed arrays is quite inexpensive...

Comment: I guess this workaround is very expensive when it comes to computational time, but I will test it. Thank you.

Comment: Not necessarily. Basically, it is about two copy operations. The `Flatten`ing and `ArrayReshape `ing is really _almost_ for free since packed arrays are stored internally as a flat vector anyways.

Comment: @Szabolcs My understand is that "proceeding with uncompiled evaluation" means that the evaluation of the `CompiledFunction` `cf` is stopped and restarted completely from the beginning by executing `cf[[7]]` as fallback. So that would make things even more expensive.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I did not know that.  Can you show it through a simple example? I'm not sure how to test for it other than through timings ...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, how would you separate them again back in MMA, after a certain element? I somehow miss the function and `Partition` will not do the trick I guess. It seems to be almost equally fast.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher  Oleksandr says the same (i.e. that it triggers a complete reevaluation). Here's an interesting approach to work around this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1783/12

Comment: @DisplayName It depends. That's why I asked for a concrete example. `TakeList` often helps.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Ah thanks, could have used `Part` as well. I think Henrik's workaround would work in principle but it feels very cumbersome.

Comment: You can use `Sow` inside of the compiled function and then `Reap` the results again afterwards when calling the function. This will cause a call to `MainEvaluate` inside of the compile function, but it shouldn't be that big of a deal in most cases I think. It would be really handy if it were possible to return associations from compiled functions, though...

Answer (score 0):

*Not an answer but too long for a comment.*

This shows that in case of `CompiledFunction::cflist`, a `CompiledFunction` `cf` will fall back to execution of `cf[[7]]`:

```
cf = Compile[{}, {{1, 2}, {3}}];
Quiet[cf[[7]] = 
  Function["args", Print["Meep!"]; "body"] /. 
  {"args" -> cf[[7, 1]], "body" -> cf[[7, 2]]};
 ];
cf[];
```

[image]

> Meep!

Comment: @Szabolcs See here for an example.